# Angular - How to redirect to localhost?

Tags: angular, nginx, hosts

If i go to public domain [www.myapp.com](http://www.myapp.com) I would run my frontend application. I created a rule on my nginx.conf.

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name myapp.com;
   location / {
     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4200;
   }
}
```

This is the package.json script:

```
"start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0  --port 4200 --configuration=it --ssl false",
```

This rule seems to work but If I try to edit code in my app I can't see it in the browser. Why?

Answer (score 0):

When you run on a specific host, code changes are not reflected on the screen immediately, and you have to reload the page to see your code changes

Comment: Not really. I tried to refresh page but nothing changes.

Comment: in package.json try to change the line to:
``"start": "ng serve --host  myapp.com  --port 4200``

Comment: I have an error: `` An unhandled exception occurred: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available `` if I try to edit the "start" script